# Query to find the sum of the values for duplicate id in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a requirement :

```
ID            Quantity
1              5
1              4
1              2
1              4
2              1
2              2
2              3
3              1
3              3
3              2
```

Output required :

```
ID          Quantity
1              15
2              6
3              6
```

I have tried the below query on MySQL but unable to get appropriate result.

```
SELECT
a.id, sum(b.Quantity)
FROM
​table_name a
INNER JOIN
​table_name b
 ON a.id = b.id
​  ​group by
a.id, b.Quantity
```

Comment: What do you mean "for duplicate id". Do you mean, ignore the ones that occur once and only sum the ones that are duplicated?

Answer (score 1):

Just remove ​`b.Quantity` from ​`group by` statement. [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0aa20/3)

```
SELECT   
a.id, sum(b.Quantity)  
FROM   
​table_name a   
INNER JOIN   
​table_name b  
 ON a.id = b.id  
​  ​group by    
a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/003625/1

```
SELECT id, SUM(quantity)
FROM `table_name`
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any `join`. Simply try:

```
select id,sum(quantity) from table_name group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` clause along with `sum()` like the query below-

```
select ID, sum(Quantity) FROM table_name GROUP BY ID;
```

Comment: The question already has a group clause with sum, how does this answer the question?

Comment: You should add relevant code and explanation to the answer.